# My computer sometimes won't turn on when plugged to the power line (I have to take of the plug and put it back again)

Tags: laptop, power-supply

So I have the following problem: My mother does not use the battery of her computer so she leaves it plugged to a extension (which you can cut the power with a switch) and when ever she does not need it, she simply switches off. But sometimes, when she switches on the switch, the light that indicates the the computer is on goes on, but the battery light won't even go on and the computer won't start. In order to put it working she has to unplug it and plug it again and then the computer will turn on and all the lights will turn on as usual.

It is toshiba, she does not have the manuals and can't see the model of the computer.
Here are the specs:
Intel Celeron(R) CPU 1000M @ 1.80 GHz 1.80 GHz

RAM 4 GB

Windows 8.1 64x

It is hard to see anything else, since I cannot physically check the computer and I do not even dare to try something like Team Viewer.

Any guess of what might be?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason as to why she isn't using a batter with her mobile device? Why doesn't she get a desktop. I'd imagine having it constantly plugged in wouldn't be good for the laptop.